# How to remove previous element in an std::list with a reverse_iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, erase, reverse-iterator

Look at this simple algorithm that remove elements around specific ones :

```cpp
void forwardRemoveAlgorithm(std::list<int> &list, int removeAround)
{
    for(std::list<int>::iterator it=list.begin(); it!=list.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it==removeAround)
        {
            list.erase(std::prev(it));
            list.erase(std::next(it));
        }
    }
}
```

it works well and everything is fine (I don't mind side-effects for now)

```cpp
std::list<int> myList = {1,2,3,4,5};
forwardRemoveAlgorithm(myList,3);
for(int elem : myList) std::cout<<elem<<std::endl;  // displays 1 3 5
```

But now, I need the reverse counterpart. And the problem becomes apocalyptic. It should look like this :

```cpp
void reverseRemoveAlgorithm(std::list<int> &list, int removeAround)
{
    for(std::list<int>::reverse_iterator it = list.rbegin(); it!=list.rend(); ++it)
    {
        if(*it==removeAround)
        {
            std::list<int>::iterator forwardEquivalent = std::next(it).base();
            list.erase(std::prev(forwardEquivalent)); // invalidate it and causes a crash at next iteration
            list.erase(std::next(forwardEquivalent));
        }
    }
}
```

Since `std::list` does not have an `erase()` function for `reverse_iterator`s, a new step appears in order to find the forward iterator equivalent. And an evil offset of one element separates the two iterators. This means that now, the algorithm deletes and invalidate the underlying forward iterator of the main reverse iterator `it`.

I wonder what is the stl way to solve this? Also, I am looking for a template version able to go backward or forward on demand.

Comment: This is gap in the C++ standard.

Comment: Once you've invalidated your reverse iterator, you'll need to reseat `it` to a valid iterator.  The easiest way is to `it = list.rbegin();` after the erases, and then loop to next until `it` gets back to `forwardEquivalent`.

Comment: @Eljay this would make the algorithm O(n²) and waste the precious time of my processor. I also successfully tried iterating backward with a forward iterator, but the solution is still dirty

Comment: Another alternative is to make the reverse iterator jump 2 ahead, then do the surrounding deletes with the forward iterator.  You'll need to not increment the reverse iterator in the `for` loop's iteration-expression (because then you'd be skipping that unchecked element).  And as you've done in the problem, none of this accounts for the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to reset your it (reverse iterator), so you can use std::make_reverse_iterator function.

Could you check the following code:

```
void reverseRemoveAlgorithm(std::list<int>& list, int removeAround)
{
    for (std::list<int>::reverse_iterator it = list.rbegin(); it != list.rend(); ++it)
    {
        if (*it == removeAround)
        {
            std::list<int>::iterator forwardEquivalent = std::next(it).base();
            list.erase(std::prev(forwardEquivalent)); // invalidate it and causes a crash at next iteration
            list.erase(std::next(forwardEquivalent));
            it = std::make_reverse_iterator(std::next(forwardEquivalent));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works, thank you. Any idea how to merge both forward and backward codes in a single function, so that it stays easy to maintain?

Comment: Welcome, but there is no way to call the erase on the reverse iterator, you should use forward iterator.
Also, be careful you should add some checks when you delete the first or the last element in the list.
If you find this useful, mark the answer is accepted.